# Reverberant set 

Tags: reverberant, location

Hey so I am doing onset recording in april, we are shooting in a abandoned hospital and I have been told some of the rooms are very reverberant and have echoes, was wondering if I could get any tips on how to handle this?

Will appreciate any help allot.

Answer (score 3):

Sound blankets outside of the visual frame, or even building some mobile baffles that you can position randomly around the rooms out of the shot. You might even be able to get away with hiding some in the shots (i.e. behind the privacy curtains and stands you frequently see in hospitals.

Bubble wrap on windows that are out of frame can be a big help to both the sound and camera/lighting departments. Diffuses outside light and breaks up a hard acoustically reflective surface.

Hypercardioid mics (as opposed to shotgun)

Taping down thin carpets or pieces of fabric for actors to stand and walk on if the floor won't be in the shot. You may want to look into ways to modify the soles of their shoes (attach some absorptive material) if stuff on the floor is going to be an issue. It would have to be something that leaves them some traction though...don't want them falling and hurting themselves. ;)

I'm sure other people will come up with some additional ideas as well.

Answer (score 1):

As Shaun mentioned, sound blankets on C stands will be a lifesaver - inch them in as close as you can to the talent to reduce reflections off the walls. But it will also  most likely be a problem for the camera and lighting departments so you'll want to coordinate with them in pre-production.

There is a great product called Hush Heels that consists of adhesive shoe-sole-shaped pieces of sound-absorbing foam designed to reduce footstep sound during production recording. I've found it pretty effective in the past.

The most important thing to think about is how much reverberation is appropriate to the scene. If the scene is set in a hospital, having some reverb is more than likely a good thing. If the director doesn't shoot closeup coverage, which will be what you'll want to use in sound editorial, definitely get closeup perspective wild lines.